# How to set `false` value to encrypted cookies in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, cookies

I have upgraded from Rails 5.2 to Rails 6.0.3.1

Before upgrade in Rails 5.2 encrypted cookies in controller worked this way:

```rb
cookies.encrypted[:my_cookie_name] = false
# cookies.encrypted[:my_cookie_name] => false
```

Now in Rails 6.0.3.1:

```rb
cookies.encrypted[:my_cookie_name] = false
# cookies.encrypted[:my_cookie_name] => nil
```

Is this behavior designed so, or it's a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does indeed looks like a bug. I submitted a patch with a fix: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39452

As a workaround you can use this for now (keep in mind it's not backwards compatible with existing cookies with metadata):

`Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.use_cookies_with_metadata = false`

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, just debugged my local gem, came almost the same. Would like to know, is it safe to just delete that comparison and left only `parse(name, data, purpose: "cookie.#{name}")`